# Routes ignored when referencing external resource as a directory

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to have a directory `src/Vendor/Bundle/Resources/config/routes/` be full of routing files (in yml). I have this:

```
# /src/Vendor/Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
route1:
    resource: "@VendorBundle/Resources/config/routes/"
```

But the routes don't get picked up and are not listed when I run the router debug in the console.

They *do* work when I reference them one by one:

```
# /src/Vendor/Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
route1:
    resource: "@VendorBundle/Resources/config/routes/myroute.yml"
```

The [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#including-external-routing-resources) state this should work but I can't get it to.

So far:

- I've cleared the cache after making changes.
- I've tried `@VendorBundle/Resources/config/routes/*` but that gives me an error (and it's not what's in the docs)

Any ideas or advice would be very helpful.

Comment: The link is perhaps not as clear as it should be but the directory approach is for route annotations defined inside of controllers.  You will need to include your route files one at a time.

Comment: Thank you Cerad! It's not obvious but it is implied I suppose. I might switch to using annotations in my controllers instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cerad answered the question:

> The link is perhaps not as clear as it should be but the directory approach is for route annotations defined inside of controllers. You will need to include your route files one at a time.